# Can i save Two-Dimensional Arrays to text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file, matrix

How can I save a 2-dimensional array into a text file with python?
I tried to do it as follows, but I get an error:

```
readcodon= open("codon.txt","r")
triplets=readcodon.read().split()
for i in range(0,len(triplets)):
   A=np.array(triplets, dtype=None)
readcodon.write(A)
```

This is the error message:

```
readcodon.write(A)

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray
```

Here is a sample of codon.txt:

```
TTT TCT TAT TGT TTC
```

The expected output in the file text:

```
[TTT, TCT, TAT, TGT, TTC ]
```

Comment: I edit it @yoonghm

Comment: I edit it @yoonghm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a file `codon.txt` with the following contents:

```
TTT TCT TAT TGT TTC
```

I don't think you need to redudantly convert the list returned from split into a numpy array to achieve your desired output:

```
with open('codon.txt', 'r+') as codon_file:
    triplets = codon_file.read().split()
    codon_file.seek(0)
    codon_file.write(f"[{', '.join(triplets)}]")
    codon_file.truncate()
```

The contents of `codon.txt` after running above:

```
[TTT, TCT, TAT, TGT, TTC]
```

If you absolutely need the output to have the extra space after the last element of the list i.e:

```
[TTT, TCT, TAT, TGT, TTC ]
```

You can add the space before the end of the [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
codon_file.write(f"[{', '.join(triplets)} ]")
#                                        ^
#                                        |
#                                        space character
```

Answer (score 1):

For ***readability and simplicity***, you can just use the `numpuy.savetxt()` **function of numpy**.

This method is used to save an array to a text file. This is an example of ***writing a 2d array into a file***:

```
# Python program explaining 
# savetxt() function 
import numpy as geek 

x = geek.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print("x is:") 
print(x) 

# X is an array 
c = geek.savetxt('geekfile.txt', x, delimiter =', ') 
a = open("geekfile.txt", 'r')# open file in read mode 

print("the file contains:") 
print(a.read())
```

Also, take a look at the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), and at the [geeksforgeeks numpuy.savetxt() guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-savetxt/) for any doubts and clarifications.

Comment: thank you very much for your help @simonedimaria

Answer (score 0):

write() function wants a string. You can make a string out of your array or you can use numpys built-in write function instead:

```
np.savetxt(readcodon,A)
```

I think there is also a mistake in your for loop, it does three times the same thing, maybe you want to use your loop index i.